# Upvoting an answer on superuser.com not incrementing vote count correctly

Tags: bug, status-norepro

[Criteria for rating LCD monitor quality](https://superuser.com/questions/5844/criteria-for-rating-lcd-monitor-quality)

On the above question, I upvoted a couple of answers with 0 vote count and the count was not incremented, but the uparrow highlighted.

Being confused by this I clicked the upvote again and the count changed to -1.

Answer (score 5):

That's probably just someone else downvoting at the same time as you upvoted. When your upvote was in place (arrow highlighted) the two cancelled each other out, leading to a total of 0. When you then undid your vote, it went down to -1.

EDIT: In particular, if you mean [Jonathan Sampson's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/5844/5845#5845), he has indeed received a downvote for it.

Comment: I don't think you can downvote a comment Jon.

Comment: nevermind, miscommunication between the OP and my face.

Comment: I've edited the body to make it clearer :)

Answer (score 1):

Jon has it right that someone else probably just downvoted at the same time.

Also, remember that the upvote arrow is like a toggle. Each time you click it it switches states (on or off).